# ATI 5850 Video Card Display Limits

Tags: video, display, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have a question regarding new ATI 5 series. I heard that there will be a special version of 5 series that supports up to 6 displays. What about a regular 5 series? I see a regular 5 series have 2 DVI + 1 HDMI + 1 DISPLAY PORT. Can I connect 4 displays at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular series can only handle up to 3 screens

> Prepare to experience a riveting high-definition gaming experience with the ATI Radeon HD 5800 Series graphics processors. Expand your visual real estate across up to **three displays** and get lost in the action with revolutionary ATI Eyefinity Technology.

Answer (score 0):

you're clearly wrong....

http://www.techradar.com/news/gaming/hands-on-ati-eyefinity-review-634244

you can run up to 6 according to this. Obviously you can run 2 cards in crossfire to allow up to 6 displays.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SU! We don't do insults like that here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect up to 5 displays if you will buy MST (Multi Stream Transport) Hub and connect it to display port. It is not cheap (about 150$).

Like this:
http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/mst-hub-1-3.html
or this:
http://www.accellcables.com/K088B-003B.html

Don't forget to check your display port version on video card.